# Cheap China solar water pump kit only runs for 10 minutes

Tags: batteries, solar-cell, multimeter, output, charge

I checked everything with a multimeter, everything seems fine. The batteries charge to full capacity. The output from the solar panel seems correct. The output from the controller seems correct.

In full sunlight it will only run for 5-10 minutes then stop.

Could it be that the solar panel is too small even though the pump is only 19W? It's just a cheap system from China. I have the option of throwing it away and upgrading to something more industrial.

I still want to know how to diagnose and solve what's wrong.

[image]

Comment: Any model numbers, sticker from the panel, pump, panel and battery ratings? Or do you want us to guess what you might have?

Comment: we can't know what goes wrong – we don't even know what it is designed to do! Irrigation pump systems often do something like short pump intervals. So, this could be intended, thermal problems, just a battery capacity limitations, or anything else. Essentially, you need to work with your vendor to get support, not ujs.

Comment: Is there at least a user manual?  Does the motor label say "Thermally Protected"?  Will the system reset and start pumping if the power is disconnected then reconnected?

Comment: A 50W solar panel gives you 50W under perfect conditions. Try a sunnier day, and aim the panel directly at the sun. If you find it runs, or runs for longer, that's the problem.

Comment: Likely similar to this from Aliexpress: https://www.aliexpress.us/item/3256804955941464.html?pdp_npi=2%40dis%21USD%21US%20%2442.61%21US%20%2429.83%21%21%21%21%21%402101c80216819896758465062ebb70%2112000031830983730%21btf&_t=pvid%3Ae4b808cf-81f9-45f1-a8c3-446bb0c60a63&afTraceInfo=1005005142256216__pc__pcBridgePPC__xxxxxx__1681989676&spm=a2g0o.ppclist.product.mainProduct&gatewayAdapt=glo2usa&_randl_shipto=US

Comment: _”Output from solar panel seems correct”_ Please show your measurements.

Comment: "50W" seems rather optimistic for a solar panel of that size (using Nedd's link), even under perfect conditions.

Comment: What is the size of this solar module? Width and length please.

Comment: This setup probably can not run the pump continuously. You will have to turn the pump on and off with some duty cycle. To put it in perspective, I have a deep freezer which draws an average of 40W, I run it on off-grid solar, and to do so consistently it takes approximately 400W of solar panels. I have a **80Ah, 12V lipo** battery and it's not quite enough, I need a larger one. ... Keep in mind that your 50W panel only produces that much for about 4 hours, and only if there is direct sunlight. On a cloudy day the power is drastically reduced. Like 1/10th of normal in my experience.

Answer (score 6):

Divide and Conquer:

Start with the pump: can you run it from a bench power supply?  Under the same loading conditions (i.e., pumping water). Measure how much current it takes.

If it works with a different power supply.

Will your battery system supply that amount of power? Can you try it with a dummy load?

Will your solar panel provide appropriate power? Can you try that with a dummy load?